# R: NAs show up when writing to a data frame, occurs inside second condition of if/else statement

Tags: r, conditional-statements, na

I'm trying to run some code in R that reads data from one data frame and writes it to a new data frame depending on conditionals about what text occurs in the first "read" data frame.

For some reason when I write to a new data frame I get "NA" values for the characters in the final column, but this only happens with the second if statement when I try to write the text "Byeeeeee", "HiThere" comes up fine.

Any insight into why this is working for the first if statement, but not the second?

input file is "testWayang", output file is "outputWayang"

Thanks!!!

```
outputWayang<-data.frame(startId=numeric(), studId=numeric(), sessNum=numeric(), startTime=numeric(), problemId=numeric(), action=character())
for(i in 1:50){

    if(testWayang[i,4]=="beginProblem"){
        outputWayang = rbind(outputWayang, c(testWayang[i,1], testWayang[i,2], testWayang[i,3], testWayang[i,7], testWayang[i+1,9], as.character("HiThere")))       
    }

    else if(testWayang[i,4]=="studentFeedback"){
        outputWayang = rbind(outputWayang, c(testWayang[i,1], testWayang[i,2], testWayang[i,3], testWayang[i,7], testWayang[i,9], as.character("Byeeeeeee")))       
    }

    write.csv(outputWayang, file="place I write my file to on my computer", append=TRUE)
}
```

Comment: There's potentially a spelling error, possibly the value of `testWayang[i,4]` that you think is "studentFeedback" is really "studentFeedback " or with a leading space. Type `levels(testWayang)` to check.

Comment: Not sure if this is a problem here but try to put the `else if` on the same line as the `}` that ends the first `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to create a vector with the `c` function that has both numeric and character values.  That will fail you. It's also the case that R newbies often fail to recognize problems related to R's default creation of factor variables. You might be able to rbind a list to an existing dataframe. Let's try with a simple example:

```
rbind( data.frame(a=1,b="y"), c(2,"n"))
  a    b
1 1    y
2 2 <NA>
Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, ri, value = "n") :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
```

So that replicates your failure; It's also the case taht you inadvertently coerced the first colum of what you might expect to be numeri class to character class:

```
> str( rbind( data.frame(a=1,b="y"), c(2,"n")) )
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ a: chr  "1" "2"
 $ b: Factor w/ 1 level "y": 1 NA
```

Just using a list also fails because of the factor issue mentioned above, but if you create the dataframe with a factor that has all possible levels then you get success:

```
rbind( data.frame(a=1,b=factor("y",levels=c("y","n"))), list(2,"n"))
  a b
1 1 y
2 2 n
```

I'n not sure what else might be going on since your didn't include enough data to do further investigation.